# how to resume application after launch another package

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to call web browser in my application , it is ok. After open browser , I try to back to my application by click back button or close browser what my application is already close. How to I resume my application to original state before open browser?

This is my code,

```
 public void btnTest(View v) {       
 String packageName = "facebook";
 String url = "http://www.google.com";
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

this is log cat..[image]

Comment: Look in the logcat. It should show you error messages about why your app is closing.

Comment: @David Wasser , logcat shows no error or warnings

Comment: Then post more of your code. This shouldn't happen so you are doing something else wrong. Did you filter the logcat? If so, don't filter it. Sometimes if you filter it you will miss something important.

Comment: @David Wasser , thank your reply .Now I get message from logcat.I already update my question.If you know the solution, may I know it.

Comment: Sorry, there isnt enough information in the logcat or your code to know what is wrong. Pleae post more code.